# element not interactable when Click textbox in modal dialog with selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to input User ID and Password, the User ID and Password is in Modal Dialog. But when I use `Click` to `WebElement` it return exceptions `element not interactable`

here's my code:

```
var btnPopUpLogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text() = 'Login']"));
btnPopUpLogin.Click();
Console.WriteLine("Button Dialog Login Clicked");

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

var formLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("form_login"));
if (formLogin.Displayed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Form Login Show");

    var userInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("userid"));
    userInput.Click();
    Console.WriteLine("Input User ID");
    userInput.SendKeys("userid");

    var passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
    passwordInput.Click();
    Console.WriteLine("Input Password");
    passwordInput.SendKeys("password");

    var btnLogin = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[text() = 'Login']"));
    btnLogin.Click();
    Console.WriteLine("Button Login Clicked");

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

it hit exception when running this: `userInput.Click();`

here's html elements:
[image]

Comment: can you include the url

Comment: @bilke url: https://bill.megaxus.co.id/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of calling the *.Click()*:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", IWebElementYouFound);
```